# How to create ViewModels in ASP.NET CORE MVC application for multiple tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I have 3 tables: 1)Agents 2)Agent Queue 3)Agent Nodes.
The AgentId is a primary key in 1) and the tables 2) & 3) are dependent on 1.
I want to create a model to access properties of these tables for one view. 
I am new to ASP.NET CORE and it would be great if anyone could point me to the right direction to do the same.

My Model Classes are:

```
public class Agents
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("Agent Id")]
        public long AgentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Last Checked")]
        public DateTime LastChecked { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Agents> agents { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AgentMachines> agentMachines { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AgentQueues> agentQueues { get; set; }
    }

public class AgentMachines
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("Machine Id")]
        public long MachineId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Agent Id")]
        public long AgentId { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string IP { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Logged User")]
        public string LoggedUser { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("AD User Account")]
        public string ADUserAccount { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Agents> agents { get; set; }
    }

public class AgentQueues
    {
        [Key]
        [DisplayName("Agent Queue Id")]
        public long AgentQueueId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Agent Id")]
        public long AgentId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Test Id")]
        public long TestId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Value Set Id")]
        public long ValueSetId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Process Id")]
        public string ProcessId { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Update User")]
        public string UpdateUser { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Schedule Time")]
        public DateTime? ScheduleTime { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Update Date")]
        public DateTime? UpdateDate { get; set; }
        public bool Deleted { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Test")]
        public string TestName { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Value Set")]
        public string ValueSetName { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Agents> agents { get; set; }
    }

public class TestAgentDetail
    {
        public IEnumerable<AgentMachines> agentMachines { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<AgentQueues> agentQueues { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Agents> agents { get; set; }
    }
```

The controller code I have so far is:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(long? id)
        {
            var viewModel = new TestAgentDetail();
            viewModel.agents = await _context.Agents
                  .Include(i => i.agentMachines)
                  .Include(i => i.agentQueues)
                  .AsNoTracking()
                  .ToListAsync();

            if (id != null)
            {
                Agents agent = viewModel.agents.Where(
                    i => i.AgentId == id.Value).Single();
                viewModel.agentMachines = agent.agentMachines.Select(s => s.LoggedUser);
            }

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure the detailed relationship between your three tables.Here is a working demo with `Agents` and `AgentQueue` one-to-many relationship,with `Agents` and `AgentsNodes` one-to-many relationship.Create a AgentViewModel to show the data:

Model:

```
public class Agents
{
    [Key]
    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    public string AgentName { get; set; }
    public AgentQueue AgentQueue { get; set; }
    public List<AgentNodes> AgentNodes { get; set; }
}
public class AgentQueue
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string QueueName { get; set; }
    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    public Agents Agents { get; set; }
}
public class AgentNodes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string NodeName { get; set; }
    public Agents Agents { get; set; }
}
public class AgentViewModel
{
    public int AgentId { get; set; }
    public string AgentName { get; set; }
    public string QueueName { get; set; }
    public List<string> NodeName { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<AgentViewModel>

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AgentId)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AgentName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NodeName)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.QueueName)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AgentId)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AgentName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @foreach (var node in item.NodeName)
                {
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => node)
                    <br />
                }
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => item.QueueName)
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller:

```
public class AgentsController : Controller
{
    private readonly MvcProjContext _context;

    public AgentsController(MvcProjContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    // GET: Agents
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var model = await _context.Agents.Include(a => a.AgentQueue).Include(a => a.AgentNodes)
                                         .Select(a => new AgentViewModel()
                                         {
                                             AgentId=a.AgentId,
                                             AgentName = a.AgentName,
                                             NodeName = a.AgentNodes.Select(an=>an.NodeName).ToList(),
                                             QueueName = a.AgentQueue.QueueName
                                         }).ToListAsync();
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

DbContext:

```
public class MvcProjContext : DbContext
{
    public MvcProjContext (DbContextOptions<MvcProjContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Agents> Agents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AgentNodes> AgentNodes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<AgentQueue> AgentQueue { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        //configure one-to-one relationship
        modelBuilder.Entity<Agents>()
            .HasOne(a => a.AgentQueue)
            .WithOne(b => b.Agents)
            .HasForeignKey<AgentQueue>(b => b.AgentId);
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: A note for the OP, we can also use [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html) in the controller to avoid the manual object conversion from LINQ query to viewmodel.

Comment: @Rena thanks for answering the question, the AgentQueues and Agentnodes both have a one to many relationship with the agents table. I just wanted to know how would i be able to display multiple values from the agent nodes in the same table?

Comment: @Rena to make the question more specific to your answer, my table AgentNodes has properties 
`public long AgentId { get; set; }
 public string Address { get; set; }
 public string IP { get; set; }`
and I want to display these multiple properties in the view.. What changes would I have to make to the viewModel for this? Do I need to have a List<> for each property?

Comment: Yes,you need have a List<> for each property due to the one-to-many relationship.If my answer helps you,could you please accept as answer?Thanks.

Comment: @Rena, Yes! I will do that. And if I want to display the nodes in a separate table for each node how would I be able to do that in the view? could you show me a code example of the same? Or maybe share some link where I can read it from

Comment: @Rena @Rena, Yes! I will do that. And if I want to display the nodes in a separate table for each node how would I be able to do that in the view? For example if I access the Nodes entity: `List<AgentNodes> nodes {get; set;}` What changes would I have to make to the controller and the View? If you could please help me with this, it would be great!

Comment: For confirmation,You just want to see the detailed notes for each node separately or want to display the related AgentNodes in Agent?

Comment: @Rena I want to display all the nodes separately in a table when I click on *View* button for the agent...

Comment: @Rena Thank you for your help, I have been reading a few articles and now it's a little jumbled in my head. Hence I thought asking a question specific to my models would help me get a better idea..

Comment: Hi @PratikshaB,I think you could use a bootstrap modal to display the nodes.Or  you could create a partial view like here:https://forums.asp.net/p/2164563/6296105.aspx?Re+Razor+pages+Partial+View+with+different+model

Comment: @Rena I did the exact same thing.. but on the next page, I also want to include the details of another table i.e dependent on the Agent which is the AgentsQueue. How can I display a new table after the click on Details?

Comment: Could you share any code?What's the error you make?

Comment: @Rena There is no error, I am able to display the agent nodes on the next page after clicking on details button. But the `@model` that I am including for the same is *agentNodes* model. I instead want to create a ViewModel where I can access all the three tables at the same time. How can I achieve that?

Comment: @Rena I have addded my model classes to the Question, could you please tell me what my controller should look like if I want to display the agent nodes and agent queues on the next page?

Comment: Oh,I know.I think your viewmodel should contain the whole three models' data.And then display each data like this line: `NodeName =a.AgentNodes.Select(an=>an.NodeName).ToList(),` in my post.

Comment: @Rena oh so I can't access it as a list? And i have to declare each property individually for the view model? What if I want to access and modify it as a List<>?

Comment: Actually you could,but it seems difficult to render the correct data and specify the data in the action.I need more time to try then give you the answer.And for you declare the each property you need modify the AgentNodes and AgentQueue's property as a list.Agent's property is no need to modify as list.

Comment: @Rena yes i will keep on searching for a few examples! please get back to me if you do find a solution to this problem! Thank you! 

[Microsoft Docs: ASP.NET Core MVC Read relatable data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

I was referring to this, but I still am confused a little, just sharing the link because it might be useful. Thank you

Comment: @Rena I have added the controller code I have so far, could you tell me what more I need to add?

Comment: @Rena, `viewModel.agentMachines = agent.agentMachines.Select(s => s.LoggedUser);` for this line of code I get an error saying **cannot implicitly convert from type IEnumerable<string> to IEnumerable<AgentMachines>**

Comment: @Rena I am getting an error, if i add an extra field AgentQueue and Agentnodes in the Agents class I am getting a SQL error. I tried doing it in your way, but it does not work either.. **An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.

SqlException: Invalid column name 'AgentsAgentId'.** This is the error